# Always-true test failing in Karma - why?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to write Karma tests for an Angular app. This test is failing:

```
describe('Controller: AdherenceCtrl', function () {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  var MainCtrl,
    scope;
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    // do nothing for the moment
    // scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // MainCtrl = $controller('AdherenceCtrl', {
    //   $scope: scope
    // });
  }));
  it('should pass a basic test', function () {
    expect([1,2].length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

If I delete the `beforeEach(inject` section, though, it passes.

```
describe('Controller: AdherenceCtrl', function () {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  var MainCtrl,
    scope;
  it('should pass a basic test', function () {
    expect([1,2].length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

What is wrong with the `beforeEach(inject` section?

The error message I get from Karma is this, which I cannot parse:

```
 Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0) Controller: AdherenceCtrl should pass a basic test FAILED
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=astellasRiskfactorcalcAppApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2Fundefined%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252Fundefined%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(%253Canonymous%253E)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A6%253A453%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A20%253A119%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A19%253A353)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A20%253A14%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A28%253A434%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Array.forEach%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A7%253A261)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A28%253A374)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fabsolute%252FUsers%252Fanna%252FDropbox%252Fprojects%252Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%252Fapp%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253F1383935561000%253A28%253A451%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A6%3A453%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A29%3A262%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A7%3A261)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A28%3A374)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A28%3A451%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A7%3A261)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fabsolute%2FUsers%2Fanna%2FDropbox%2Fprojects%2Fastellas-riskfactorcalc-app%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F1383935561000%3A28%3A374)
            at Error (<anonymous>)
            at /Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:453
            at /Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:29:262
            at Array.forEach (native)
            at q (/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:261)
            at e (/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:28:374)
            at Object.Xb [as injector] (/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:32:427)
            at workFn (/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/test/angular-mocks.js:2114:52)
```

Comment: Maybe you will get a clear error if you don't use angular.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the URL decoded stack trace:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=astellasRiskfactorcalcAppApp&p1=Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngRoute&p1=Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:6:453
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:20:119
at a (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:19:353)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:20:14
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:434
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:7:261)
at e (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:374)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:451
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:6:453
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:29:262
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:7:261)
at e (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:374)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:451
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:7:261)
at e (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/anna/Dropbox/projects/astellas-riskfactorcalc-app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?1383935561000:28:374)
```

It mentions `ngRoute` in line 1. The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3amodulerr) says:

> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.

If you are using Angular 1.2.x, have you tried adding `ngRoute` as a dependency of `myApp`?

Comment: Phew - you really helped me, thank you. (To fix the error, I needed to add the path to the angular-route dependence in my Karma config file.) I didn't realise it was URL-encoded, now I know how to read future errors too. Thank you!